# How to detect when the application crashed and save a log of that

Tags: java, android

I want to detect when the application is getting crashed , and need to save the log of what exceptions it encountered , as we get in the logcat in eclipse.

Comment: 8.37 is not an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)

Comment: 8.37 is not an Integer, 8.37 is a floating point number.  You will need to parse it with a NumberFormat or with Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat

Answer (score 4):

8.37 is not an integer, it needs to be a float or double

Answer (score 0):

8.37 is not an integer, it's a floating point number.

You can do something like

```
float f = Float.valueOf("8.37");
```

or you could consider using

```
new BigDecimal("8.37");
```

if you need absolute precision.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
string strSomePerc = "8.99%";

// For the real number.
double dSomePerc = Convert.ToDouble(strSomePerc.Replace("%", String.Empty));

// For the integer.
int nSomePerc = Convert.ToInt32(dSomePerc);
```

Note, (as Andrew Logvinov has stated) if a number has a decimal point in it, it cannot be part of the integer gang.